# How do I get two stepper motors to rotate at the exact same time and in the same direction using only one Arduino Uno?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

My current code:

```
    #include <Stepper.h>

    const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution


    Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    Stepper secondStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

    void setup() {
    // set the speed at 60 rpm:
    myStepper.setSpeed(60);
    // initialize the serial port:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    secondStepper.setSpeed(60);
    // initialize the serial port:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    }

    void loop() {
    // step one revolution  in one direction:
    Serial.println("clockwise");
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
    Serial.println("clockwise");
    secondStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
    delay(500);
    }
```

I was working on a project involving the above code during a hackathon this past weekend, but I couldn't get the two motors to move simultaneously. I was wondering if anyone on here knew how to do it properly so that I may be better prepared in the future.

I'm using the Arduino IDE, if that matters.

Comment: 'exact' same time can be considered impossible.  You need to put an accuracy in there; so within 5ms or 5ns ...  But a quick breakdown of your problem:  You've got 9600b/s, and you're sending ... 10bytes at least - which means you've got a delay of, at the VERY MINIMUM of 1ms.  Ignoring any delay at the other ends in processing the message.  You could half that minimum delay by changing "clockwise" and "anticlockwise" to be enums.

Comment: Can you wire the both motor controls in parallel?  This will ensure that what is done to one motor is done to the other.  I don't see how this is a programming issue. :-)

Comment: Find a non-blocking stepper library.

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-blocking step (or start) call that starts the motion and returns immediately.  After starting the two motions, you would then wait for an asynchronous callback from each motor indicating that the motion has completed.  One thread per motor would work in a straightforward manner.  The main thread would wait for both motor threads to complete before proceeding.

Comment: Pity.  If the steppers are interrupt driven, you can accomplish the same thing in the main routine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can wire the both motor in parallel, that how the z axis is controlled on the Ramps 1.4 board!

Comment: Please describe your answer little bit more.

Comment: You just need to wire your motors in parallel, plug them in on the same port, if you look  at the z axis on the Ramps1.4 board, it accepts two stepper, it is already wired in parallel!